# При компиляции кода python в exe, координаты курсора мыши отображаются неправильно win32api GetCursorPos

Tags: python, winapi, cursor

Я хочу выводить координаты курсора. Когда я запускаю исходник(main.py), то все координаты отображаются правильно, но когда я компилирую этот код в exe, то происходит что то непонятное, координаты курсора вдруг отображаются так, посмотрите ниже. Разрешение моего экрана 1920x1080

Исходник(main.py)

```
from win32api import GetCursorPos

while True:
    cursor_pos = GetCursorPos()
    print(cursor_pos[0], cursor_pos[1]) # X, Y
```

Вот какой вывод я получаю и он правильный (мой курсор находится в правом верхнем углу)

```
...
1919 0
1919 0
1919 0
```

А вот что он мне выводит когда я скомпилировал код, напоминаю у меня разрешение экрана 1920x1080 (курсор также находится в правом верхнем углу)

```
...
1535 0
1535 0
1535 0
```

Ну вот и как это понять...? С координатой Y таже проблема.
Вот кстати команда pyinstaller с которой я компилировал это

```
pyinstaller -F main.py
```